# QField on iPhone: is it possible to authenticate Postgis layers using connection service file pg_service.conf?

Tags: postgis, qfield, ios, iphone

While using QField on Android phones to work with Postgis layers, I can authenticate with my login information stored in the file `pg_service.conf`, which is placed at `Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\QField`. Is there any way to do the same with QField on iPhone?

I've been tested with the same `.qgs` project and `pg_service.conf` file placing at `On My iPhone\QField` or `On My iPhone\QField\auth` to no avail.